# MissingSetupFile Removed webpart in gallery still receive error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, health-analyzer

I looked up a webpart and the only reference was to the web part gallery of the site. I removed the webpart from the list and recycle bin, but when I do a health check the error still persists.

The database still has the entry for the deleted webpart. Should I delete the entry in the database?

Update:
I've found the file by GUID. The results I receive are:

```
EffectiveRawPermissions : 
EffectiveAuditMask      : 
Exists                  : False

 .....

ParentFolder            : 
Url                     : 
UniqueId                : 40a56c20-3e6f-4f8b-9f4a-ab17abf04577
ServerRelativeUrl       : 

 ..... 

IsConvertedFile         : False
SourceLeafName          : 
SourceUIVersion         : 
GeneratingConverterId   : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
SourceFile              : 

ServerRedirected        : 
IsIRMed                 : False
IsSharedAccessRequested : False
EventReceivers          :
```

Since 'Exists : False' should I just delete the db entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most annoying message i witnessed in SharePoint, when you remove a solution from a farm but for some odd reason it still stay in some places.

their are couple of tools available to remove all the reference of the webpart.

- [SharePoint Manager 2013](http://spm.codeplex.com/)
- Use one of the script [from this blog:](http://www.danielroot.info/2014/05/two-sharepoint-scripts-for-those.html)

MissingSetupFiles Script(Read instruction from Above Blog)

```
    param($filename, $delete = $false)
function Run-SQLQuery ($SqlServer, $SqlDatabase, $SqlQuery)
{
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server =" + $SqlServer + "; Database =" + $SqlDatabase + "; Integrated Security = True"
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $SqlConnection.Close()
    $DataSet.Tables[0]
}
$dbs = get-spcontentdatabase
$dbs | %{
 $db = $_
 $db.Name
 $files = Run-SQLQuery -SqlServer $db.Server -SqlDatabase $db.Name -SqlQuery "SELECT * from AllDocs where SetupPath LIKE '%' +'$filename'" | select Id, SiteId, DirName, LeafName, WebId, ListId
 $files | ?{$_.SiteId -ne $null} | %{
 $file = $_
 $site = get-spsite $file.SiteId
 $web = $site.AllWebs | ?{$_.Id -eq $file.WebId}
 $spfile = $web.GetFile([Guid]$file.Id)
 $web.Site.WebApplication.Url + $spfile.ServerRelativeUrl
 if ($delete -eq $true){
  $spfile.Delete()
 }
 }
}
```